# Почему в метод третьего класса выводит 0, а не 1 ???? как третий класс в методе видел значение второго класса присвоенного первым?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Output output = new Output();
        output.x=1;
        System.out.println(output.x);

        Input input = new Input();
        input.foo();
    }
}
```

//// второй отдельный класс

```
public class Output {

    public int x;

}
```

////// третий класс

```
public class Input extends Output{

    public void foo(){
       System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Выводит `0` ибо Вы не задаете никакого значения. В объекте примитивы по умолчанию равны `0` или же `false` в случае `boolean` типа.

В коде:

```
Output output = new Output();
output.x=1;
System.out.println(output.x);

Input input = new Input();
input.foo();
```

Вы создаете абсолютно два разных объекта(`output` и `input`), которые с собой никак не связаны (Имеют разные ссылки в `heap`-е. Окромя того что класс `Input` расширяет класс `Output`.

Что бы было так как нужно нужно сделать так:

```
Output output = new Output();
output.x=1;
System.out.println(output.x);

Input input = new Input();
input.x=1;
input.foo();
```

> как третий класс в методе видел значение второго класса присвоенного
>   первым?

Класс `Input` видит поле `x` ибо он наследуется от `Output`-а. Если же вы сделаете это поле `private`, то наследнику не удастся получить доступ к полю `x`. Наследование говорит о том что класс наследник наследует все что есть у родителя, то бишь перенимает на себя (прям как в жизни, когда людям достаются наследства от богатых родителей и т.д.)

**UPDATE:**

Можно сделать так:

```
public class Input {

    public int x;

    public Input() {}

    public Input(Output output) {
       this.x = output.x;
    }

    public void foo(){
       System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

теперь это будет работать:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Output output = new Output();
        output.x=1;
        System.out.println(output.x);

        Input input = new Input(output);
        input.foo();

    }
}
```

Comment: мне не нужно принудительно присваивать "1" в класс Input, нужно из main изменить x находящееся в Output, а затем это переданное значение использовать в третьем отдельном классе. Получается третий класс никак не может использовать значения второго класса, которые подверглись изменению первым main классом???

Comment: @Stanislav так не работает ни наследование ни `java`. Это нужно делать ручками или же создавать объект `Input` и передать в него объект класса `Output` и при этом убрать наследование между `Input` и `Output`.

Comment: @Stanislav Вы создали два объекта которые никак между собой не связаны. Если вы хотите сказать второму объекту изменить значение нужно сделать это руками или же как я предложил выше.

Comment: @Stanislav обновил ответ. Смотрите блок UPDATE

Comment: поменял Input, всеравно в консоли 1 и затем 0 , а не 1 и 1. Переменная x в третьем классе = не получает "1"

Comment: @Stanislav а вы в `Input` используете объект у которого поле `x` стоит `1` или создаете новый `Output` объект?

Comment: отдельный класс отдельным файлом:

Comment: public class Output {

    public int x;

}

Comment: Инпут также отдельным файлом

Comment: @Stanislav про `Output` и отдельные файлы я понял. А вот в `Input` вы используете (в конструкторе) уже измененный объект класса `Output`? или же создаете новый?

Comment: @Stanislav Вы наверно делаете `new Input` и при этом не передаете туда объект класса `Output`, который создали ранее.

Comment: @Stanislav нужно вот так: `Input input = new Input(output);`

Comment: Спасибо я понял, заработало

Comment: @Stanislav Если ответ помог отметьте его решением, пожалуйста)